# Apache Jena - which reasoner to choose to get instances and properties?

Tags: jena, ontology, apache-jena

I want to use jena api to manipulate the ontology that I have. I want to get subclasses of a class, instances of a class and properties of instance.

Data would look like below:

```
gv:AInstance
   rdf:type ex:AClass;
   core:containsProperty gv:AInstanceProperty;
 .
 gv:AInstanceProperty
   rdf:type core:Property ;
   core:isDescribedByRole gv:AInstancePropertyRole ;
   rdfs:comment "some comment" ;
   rdfs:label "A Instance Property" 
.
gv:AInstancePropertyRole
  rdf:type core:PropertyRole;
  corerepr:hasSignalType corerepr:Digital
.
```

In the above example, I would like to get all instances of 'AClass' and its properties(AInstanceProperty) and relation between property and its role ('AInstancePropertyRole').

Can someone  please tell which reasoner to use get the above information?
Thansks